# JS and CSS not getting served with HTNL from subroute in ExpressJS

Tags: express, static, routes

I finally got around to fidelling with expressJS. I have written a simple RestAPI and also want to serve some static HTML that consumes (via clientside-JavaScript) my RestAPI.

The RestAPI works fine, but on some subroutes CSS and JS files are looked up under the wrong URL.

I have the following directory setup:

```
src
|---models
|---controllers
|---views
     |---css
          |---main.css
     |---js
          |---core.js
     |---html
          |---login.html
          |---payments.html
     |---static
```

Both HTML files link to e.g. the core.js using

```
<script src="core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the footer.

The index.js looks as follows:

```
var app = express();
...
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/html'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use( express.static( "src/views/js") );
app.use( express.static( "src/views/css") );
app.use( express.static( "src/views/static") );
...
app.get('/:env/:org', function(req, res){
    res.render('payments.html');
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('login.html');
})
```

Now the strange thing is, that if I call myserver.com/ the login page gets displayed with all styles and JS functionality, but if I open myserver.com/path1/path2 ExpressJS tries to look up the files under myserver.com/path1/ (e.g. myserver.com/path1/main.css) instead myserver.com/main.css.

The HTML for where it does not work (that get sent vie the /path1/path2 route) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    <title>Greatpay login</title>
</head>
<body data-pagetype="login">
<header class="header">
    <img src="logo.png"/>
</header>
<div class="body">
    <div class="loginbox">
    <span class="error"></span>
        <div class="fieldline">
            <span>Organisation:</span>
            <input type="text" name="organisation"/>
            <div class="clear"><!---clear---></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldline">
            <span>Environment:</span>
            <select name="environment"/>
                <option value="TEST">Test</option>
                <option value="PROD" selected="selected">Production</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clear"><!---clear---></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldline">
            <span>Username:</span>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <div class="clear"><!---clear---></div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldline">
            <span>Password:</span>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <button id="login">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this and explain why this behaves like that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code of an html file where you're using the assets please....

Comment: Ok, I have added the HTML.

Comment: As I can see, you're setting the view folder in adding the prefix `view`, but you're prefixing 'src' during your static folders definitions. I think you should look at this...

Comment: Thought so too, but when I prefix src/view instead of view, it looks at sr/src/view. By the way, I am hosting on heroku.

Comment: You have relative paths, I think you'll need absolute paths here `<script src="/core.js"` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"/>`

Comment: That did the trick!!! Thanks alot. Please post this as an answer, so I can upvote and accept it. Cheers